# Example from Chapter 1 of iphone 3D programming book not drawing to screen.

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm learning OpenGL-ES with [3D programming for the iPhone](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596804831) (O'Reilly). Its first tutorial involves drawing the background of the screen grey. I've entered in all the code to the letter and it runs without error, but I get no color...just black. Since it runs fine, there is no bug message.

There are a few very small source files and rather then post all the code here I've zipped up the project and made it available for [download here](http://ericbrotto.com/temporary/HelloArrow.zip). I don't know if it is too much to ask for people to look at, but I'm really pulling my hair out looking at code that executes without a hitch, but has no output.

Please let me know if I can be of any help to get to the bottom of this issue.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I just made the same mistake!

Comment: Your link is broken. Do you still have the source code from the book? If so, please add it to your question. This is a perfect example of why links should be accompanied by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create your renderbuffer as a framebuffer.  If you go to GLView's `-initWithFrame:` method and change the appropriate lines to read

```
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &renderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);
```

this renders just fine.

Are you sure this is the code from the book?  It doesn't match what I have in the version in front of me.  The author properly configures the renderbuffer in the book text.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I feel a bit foolish as it was completely a copying error, but sometimes you just need that extra set of eyes. I really do appreciate the help. Thanks again!